# MeteorJS error "Invalid modifier. Modifier must be an object"

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

When the `if` statements containing `UserSession.insert` is removed, everything works fine. But when its icluded, we get te error about an invalid modifier.

What went wrong? Thank you!

**server/helpers/b.s**

```
Meteor.startup(function(){

    // Initialize
    var SUPERPACK = Meteor.require('superpack');
    var superpack = new SUPERPACK('a', 'b');


    // Get Account Info
    try {
        superpack.getInfoSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(superpack.getInfo.bind(superpack));
        var data = superpack.getInfoSync();

        // THIS PART WHEN REMOVED, REMOVES THE ERROR *********
        // Update if record exist, create if not
        if (UserSession.find().count() == 0) {

            UserSession.insert({ 'userId': 1, 'account': data});

        } else {

            UserSession.update({ 'userId': 1, 'account': data});

        }

        console.log(data);

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

});
```

**Error:**

```
superpack.getInfoSync(): Error: Invalid modifier. Modifier must be an object.
```

Comment: Where is that part with `if` statement and `Session.set()`?

Comment: @AntoJurkovic I have added another line of comment to mark that part of the code. Sorry I meant "UserSession.insert"

Comment: This rule `...count() > 0` is ok? On the first thouught I expect `update()` after that?

Comment: @AntoJurkovic You are right. I have made changed it to `if( ...count()== 0)`. The original error persists.

Comment: It seem that you also need some modifier for `update()`function: `collection.update(selector, modifier, [options], [callback])`

Comment: @AntoJurkovic You got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are two errors:

The first one is with `if` statement:

```
if (UserSession.find().count() > 0) {
```

should be changed to

```
if (UserSession.find().count() == 0) {
```

The second one: There is missing proper modifier for `update()`

```
UserSession.update({ 'userId': 1, 'account': data});
```

From documentation:

```
collection.update(selector, modifier, [options], [callback])
```

`selector` and `modifier` has to be provided.